# $http undefined error when fetching data from asp.net controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am using angularjs in asp.net

I made a controller with CRUD and am trying to get data from angularjs controller using $http service

Route params is getting correct querys from url, i tested that, but i get undefined error when requesting data

What am i doing wrong? :(

SongsController.cs method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        /*var result = db.Songs.ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);*/

        string searchString = id;
        var songs = from m in db.Songs
                    select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            songs = songs.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return Json(songs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

songsService.js:

```
myApp.factory('songsService', ['$http', function ($http) {
var songsService = {};

songsService.getSongs = function (param) {
    return $http.get('/Songs/Index/' + param);
}

return songsService;}])
```

songsController.js:

```
myApp.controller('songsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'songsService', function ($scope, $routeParams, songsService) {
var search = $routeParams.query;
if (search == 'undefined' || search == null)
    search = '';

getSongs(search);
function getSongs(searchText) {
    songsService.getSongs(searchText)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.songs = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
}}]);
```

EDIT:
Song class:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Song
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Navigation> Navigations { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT2: Navigation class:

```
using System;

public class Navigation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SongID { get; set; }
    public int PlaylistID { get; set; }

    public virtual Song Song { get; set; }
    public virtual Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT3:
If I name my .cs controller SongsController and navigate to url songs/index/something i get popup if i want to open or save something.json and just get redirected back to my default url defined by ngroute (#/songs/)

But, if i name .cs controller something else, like RandomController, if i navigate to same url i get this error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Navigation_7A1A3B789B740F23BAB0A6DAABE519BE3A‌​F91C300893047C23FF2FD8C44E6705'.

EDIT4: I've come to point at which everything if my SongsController.cs looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var song = new List<Song>
        {
            new Song{Title="Paint It Black",Artist="Rolling Stones"},
            new Song{Title="People Are Strange",Artist="The Doors"},
            new Song{Title="With Or Without You",Artist="U2"},
            new Song{Title="Wish You Were Here",Artist="Pink Floyd"},
            new Song{Title="Fluorescent Adolescent",Artist="Arctic Monkeys"},
            new Song{Title="La Guitarra",Artist="Orjan Nilsen"},
            new Song{Title="Ping Pong",Artist="Armin Van Buuren"},
            new Song{Title="Fade Out Lines",Artist="The Avenger"},
            new Song{Title="Redemption Song",Artist="Bob Marley"},
            new Song{Title="Wherever I May Roam",Artist="Metallica"},
        };
        return Json(songs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);*/
    }
```

If it' like that everything works, but if it looks like i've wrote in original post i get undefined error when i run $http.get :/

EDIT5: Okay, I believe the problem is i'm trying to send objects containing array of Navigation class objects, how can i solve this? :(

Comment: Could you share your `Songs` class? Have you checked for circular reference? Also, it is always a good practice not to return the entity objects themselves, try making a projection and/or a model class for the returning values.

Comment: I added the Song class, Songs is part of context class PlayerContext

Comment: Did you try executing the get request independent of Angular by just copy and pasting the url into your browser? Does that return anything? If not the problem is probably that you don't have your routing setup properly in MVC:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: If i do that i get this error:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Navigation_7A1A3B789B740F23BAB0A6DAABE519BE3AF91C300893047C23FF2FD8C44E6705'.

Comment: Added Navigation class

PLUS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular reference on your `Song` class.

When the Json serializer tries to process it, it finds the `Navigations` property and tries to serialize that as well, the problem is that each `Navigation` object on that collection have a instance of the same `Song`, so it enters a infinite loop trying to serialize all of it over and over again.

That happens because EntityFramework has its lazyloading and automatically populate the classes as the serializer tries to access them.

To fix it, you can do two things, simply disable the lazyloading for that call in particular:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    string searchString = id;
    var songs = from m in db.Songs
                select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        songs = songs.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return Json(songs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The other option is to create a model with only the data you need to return and populate it manually (or using a mapper tool).

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    string searchString = id;
    var songs = from m in db.Songs
                select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        songs = songs.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    var mappedSongs = songs.Select(it => new { Title = it.Title, Artist = it.Artist }).ToList();

    return Json(mappedSongs , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank You!
I chose the second option and got it working :)